# Problema com gráfico em tempo real C#

Tags: c#, graphics

Estou tentando desenhar um gráfico em tempo real.

Nesse gráfico eu vou desenhando o sinal do ponto `(0,y)` até ao ponto `(Width,y)` usando um cursor vermelho para saber onde está desenhando atualmente. 
Quando o gráfico atingir o valor da propriedade `Width`, deve retornar ao início `(ponto(0,y))`. 
Ao iniciar novamente o desenho do gráfico eu devo ir apagando as colunas de `pixels` a frente do cursor vermelho.

Para exemplificar estou anexando o código:

```
public class GraphControl : Control
{
    int contador = 0;
    public int _minValue;
    public int _maxValue;
    public int _dataCount;
    private List<float> _values1 = new List<float>();

    public GraphControl()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

    public void AddValue(float value1)
    {
        _values1.Add(value1);
        contador++;
        if (contador == 3)
        {
            Invalidate();
            contador = 0;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(95, 95, 95), 1.5f)) e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        var wid = (float)Width / (float)_dataCount;

        var total = _maxValue - _minValue;

        var lastPoint1 = new PointF(0F, (float)(Height / 2));
        PointF newPoint1 = new PointF();

        for (int i = 0, a = 0; i < _values1.Count; i++, a++)
        {
            float value;
            try
            {
                value = (float)(_values1[i]);
            }
            catch
            {
                value = (float)(_values1[i - 1]);
            }

            var porcent = value / total;

            if (porcent > 1) porcent = 1;
            var hg = porcent * (Height / 4);

            newPoint1.X = (a + 1) * wid;

            if (porcent >= 1) newPoint1.Y = Height / 4 - hg;
            else newPoint1.Y = Height / 4 - hg - 1;

            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lastPoint1, newPoint1);

            lastPoint1 = newPoint1;

            //cursor vermelho
            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Red, 2)) e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new PointF((a+1)*wid,0), new PointF((a+1)*wid,Height));

            //apagando coluna de pixel (com cinza, cor do grafico)
            using (var p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(53, 53, 53))) e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new PointF((a + 2) * wid, 0), new PointF((a + 2) * wid, Height));

            if (a == _dataCount) a = 0;
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Há dois problemas com o código:

- O cursor vermelho é desenhado várias vezes durante todo o percurso fazendo um borrão vermelho na tela
- O jeito que eu estou apagando os próximos pixels não
  funciona.

Alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema ou dar dicas da resolução? 
Procurei em vários fóruns e não encontrei nada relacionado.

Comment: Felipe, pensa assim, a cada ciclo de desenho ou seja a cada finalização de um gráfico desenhado, você precisa apagar toda a tela e redesenhar atualizando-o, acho que você está mantendo o desenho anterior.

Comment: Justamente amigo, queria que o cursor vermelho fosse apagando tudo que vem a frente dele (o gráfico que estava desenhado) e não limpar toda tela para redesenhar.

Comment: Como eu posso redesenhar uma linha em outro lugar ao inves de desenhar outra linha?